# Calculate which quantity packages to use based on quantity of bookings

Tags: algorithms, ruby, ruby-on-rails

In my app, many appointments can be booked for activities.  Each activity has many price packages with a price and a quantity.

On showing the cart, I need to work out what combination of packages to use to get the user the best prices and allow all the appointments to be accounted for.

There is not always a quantity 1 package.

Is there a common pattern to apply to this?

Here is where I got to before I realised how hard this was going to be:

```
cost = 0
i = appointments.count
activity.packages.order(:quantity => :asc).each do |package|      
   if i >= package.quantity &&  i.modulo(package.quantity) == 0                   
     cost = cost + (package.price * i/package.quantity )
     i = i - i/package.quantity
   end  
end
if i > 0 
  raise "error: packages do not cover number of children."
end
```

That's in ruby(rails).

So the problem I didn't see until I wrote the above is, what if there are 8 appointments, and packages for 4 & 5  - it will use the 5 package, then the last 3 won't fit in a 4 package and it will fail.

EDIT: More detail

So the structure is

```
activities has_many packages
packages:  
 quantity: integer
 price: float
```

So a package defines a price for a bundle of appointments for an activity.

So for example, sailing lessons are $500 for 5 or $430 for 4.

If the user orders 8 sailing lessons, the app needs to work out that it should use two of the quantity 4 packages = $860

If the user order 9 sailing lessons, the app should work out they need 1 Quantity 5 package, and one quantity 4 package.  etc

Comment: This is a typical case of a [knapsack problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem)

Comment: thanks @BartvanIngenSchenau - interesting read. Bit scary though.  What i've got running at the moment is giving some reasonable results, as long as I impose some limits on what options there can be, as recommended by jan below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not solvable if the required number of appointments cannot be written as a sum of the available *Package.Quantity* numbers.

But maybe that requirement is too strict. Why not say that you want to offer the client the cheapest available sum of packages? E.g. if he wants 8 appointments but you can't match 8, you give him e.g. 5+4 packages.

Let your package definitions follow these rules:

*if Quantity for Package1 is larger than Quantity for Package2, then

1) The price for Package1 is higher than the price for Package2, and 

2) The average Price/Quantity for Package1 is <= Price/Quantity for Package2
3) You always have a Package with quantity 1*

Then you can do the following (best illustrated with a numeric example):

Assume you have these packages:

```
12 for 600 = avg 50
10 for 550 = avg 55
5 for 500 = avg 100
4 for 400 = avg 100
3 for 360 = avg 120
2 for 260 = avg 130
```

The client wants 8 appointments
Alternatives that match exactly are e.g.
5+3 = price 860 avg 108
4+4 = price 800 avg 100
But '10 for 550' would be the best solution if you want to minimize the price: 550

So assuming the conditions earlier:
1) If exact quantity match -> take that (you don't want to go 'higher' because that reduces your sales unnecessarily)
2) If not, take package with quantity 'next up' (the 10)
3) If that does not exist, you have to 'walk down'

3a) Try to find an exact sum from the highest quantities possible,
i.e. the lowest number of packages combined
That is because you know that these have the lowest average costs
All possible combinations are:

```
5+3       860   avg 108
4+4       800   avg 100
4+2+2     920   avg 115
3+3+2     980   avg 123
2+2+2+2   1040  avg 130
```

So you have 2 candidates with only two packages.
Take the one with the lowest price (4+4).

If you do not have a package with quantity 1 you need a step 3b (but then I cannot get my head around the algorithm), OR you can also predefine the packages so that all combinations can be made - with the sample quantities I gave (2,3,4,5,10,12) you can fulfill any number with this algorithm.

Comment: Thanks jan, cheapest available sum of packages is definitely what i want to offer. I don't understand your solution though. Could you explain it a bit more please?

Comment: in this example, the answer is obviously 2x4 packages for $860, not 1x5 + 1x4  = $930.

Comment: I've re-read your answer a few times : ) Yes, this is what i have been trying since i wrote the question.  Retry the loop without the largest package until it fits.  Correct?

Comment: Thanks very much for this Jan. This is the direction I have gone in, and It is working ok given some conditions like you say - bigger packages are cheaper per item.  It's proving quite challenging, especially as there is talk of enforcing appointments to be for consecutive events to qualify for a package!